# Python Scraping Expedia data by beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scraping the hotel data from expedia. For example, scraping all the hotel link in Cavendish, Canada, from 01/01/2020 to 01/03/2020. But the problem now is I can only **scrape** 20 of them and it is actually contains 200+ for each place. The sample webpage and its url is like:

https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?adults=2&destination=Cavendish%20Beach%2C%20Cavendish%2C%20Prince%20Edward%20Island%2C%20Canada&endDate=01%2F03%2F2020&latLong=46.504395%2C-63.439669&regionId=6261119&rooms=1&sort=RECOMMENDED&startDate=01%2F01%2F2020

Scraping code:

```
import lxml
import re
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import xlwt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?adults=2&destination=Cavendish%20Beach%2C%20Cavendish%2C%20Prince%20Edward%20Island%2C%20Canada&endDate=01%2F03%2F2020&latLong=46.504395%2C-63.439669&regionId=6261119&rooms=1&sort=RECOMMENDED&startDate=01%2F01%2F2020'

header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get(url,headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

t1 = soup.select('a.listing__link.uitk-card-link')
```

So every link is stored in `<a class='listing__link.uitk-card-link' href=xxxxxxx> </a>` inside `<li></li>`, there is no differences between the html structure, can anyone explain this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Help by voting and accepting answer if its help you or work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using API call to get next 20 records. There is no way to **scrape** the next 20 records.

Here is API details they are using when you click on "Show More"

[API LINK](https://www.expedia.com/hotel-shop/api/1/en_US/hotels?accessibility=&amenities=&deals=&destination=Cavendish%20Beach%2C%20Cavendish%2C%20Prince%20Edward%20Island%2C%20Canada&endDate=2020-01-03&latLong=46.504395%2C-63.439669&lodging=&paymentType=&price=&regionId=6261119&sort=RECOMMENDED&star=&startDate=2020-01-01&travelerType=&useRewards=true&bedroomFilter=&propertyStyle=&rewards=&localDateFormat=M%2Fd%2Fyyyy&count=50&startingIndex=150&adults=2)

They have API authentication to get data using API calls.

**Note**: Scraping works only when you don't have any ajax call and no authentication method.

Comment: I was thinking about this reason and now confirmed, thanks man.